# Question about 7 segment 4 digit led custom board

Tags: led, esp32, 7segmentdisplay

I have problem that is driving me nuts and I am hoping another pair of eyes can help me see the light.

I have made a custom board using the esp32 as a micro controller.  On that board i have breakout headers for many different pins.
I then made another board that connects to the first board and it also has headers to connect 3 7 segment 4 digit leds that i bought from ebay.

This combination works perfectly fine.

I then made a third board.  This one has 4 7segment 4 digit leds which are actually on the board, including each one with its own tm1637 chip.  I can not get this last board to work.  I have studied the tm1637 datasheet to make sure that i am connecting correctly but after manufacturing 2 boards i have run out of potential problems.

I have verified that the headers that connect board 2 to board 1 are the same that the headers that connect board 3 to board 1.
Since board 1 and 2 work fine, i am assuming my problem is in board 3.

Also, as it can be seen in the schematics included, there are 5 WS2812 leds, those work fine so that verifies that V50 is getting to the board.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand what your issue is but are you sure it's a hardware problem? What's the software you're using to drive this? What does the code look like?

Comment: Hi, I am using  https://github.com/avishorp/TM1637.git as a library and even using the simplest example does not work

Comment: Does the seven segment board work with the esp board? . i.e., does it work at all?

Comment: yes, the board works with the esp board.   There are ws2812 leds which work fine and also, the en and io2 pins of the esp32 board are connected to buttons on the other board and they work fine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Digits are common cathode (CC)
[image]
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809200015_Shenzhen-Zhihao-Elec-FJ3461AH_C10708.pdf

But the driver is for common anode with segments rated for [sink current](https://www.mcielectronics.cl/website_MCI/static/documents/Datasheet_TM1637.pdf).
[image]

[Looks like you need these.](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01DKISMXK/ref=as_li_ss_tl?dchild=1&keywords=tm1637.&language=en_US&sr=8-5&linkCode=g12&linkId=49c501ba955104606757935e7fa979c3&tag=audiocruiserca-20)

[image]

Murphy's Law strikes again.

Comment: indeed murphy hits me again.  I guess now i need to either find a library that supports common cathodes or find common anodes in jlcpcb.  thanks for the observation

Comment: It's not a library issue, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: yes, you are correct.  I just sent a new board to manufacturing using common anode modules